# Probability that 2 or more digits take the same value

Tags: probability, combinations

Let $A$ a finite set with $|A| = n$, and let $A_1, \dots, A_k$ i.i.d. uniformly distributed in $A$ i.e. $\mathbb{P}(A_1 = a) = 1/n$ for all $a \in A$. I want to know the probability that exist a pair $A_i$, $ A_j$, $i\neq j$ such that $A_i = A_j$, i.e. I want to know the probability of the event $$\bigcup_{i \neq j}\{A_i = A_j\}$$
I tried to calculate the probability of the complement of that event hoping to use the independence of the variables but I couldn't get any results.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is also known as the birthday problem. A very famous problem in probability.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

If $k>n$, then at least one digit is repeated twice. Therefore probability is $1$.

If $k\le n$, then the complement has probability $\frac{n}{n} \times \frac{n-1}{n} \times {n-2}{n}\dots \frac {n-k+1}n=\frac{n!}{(n-k)!n^n}$, representing that first digit is free, second is anything but first, etc. Therefore, your answer is $1-\frac{n!}{(n-k)! n^n}$ if $k\le n$.